# Finder window file view header looks odd - fix?

Tags: macos, finder

I think I set this up some time ago and it looks like a search or something but I want it to just be like my apps folder where I can sort. My mistake but very unintuitive how to remove this:

[image: bad]

and make it look like this:

[image]

How do I remove thhat so it works like my applications folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the "arrange" button on your Finder toolbar, then choose "none".  I agree that this is quite unintuitive.

Comment: thx, fixed it well (have to wait a few minutes to accept)